# ILIKE and Subquery Issue

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, postgresql

am struggling in ilike operation in pgSQL

```
select * from gtab47 where areaname ilike '(select place from gcompany where companyid=3)%'
```

how to correct it ?

Comment: Always show your PostgreSQL version *and the exact text of any error message*. Edit your question and comment here when done.

Comment: Please clarify this rudimentary question.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter i got the ans already , anyways thanks for the comment

Comment: @superman: Good you have an answer. But this is a public forum and if your question is useless for other people, please delete it. Or improve it.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter next time i will keep your words :)

Comment: I am talking about *this* time. Press [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/22471529/edit) under your question to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things wrong here.

Subqueries aren't quoted and you must use `||` to concatenate strings, so you probably want to write something like:

```
select * 
from gtab47 
where areaname ilike (select place || '%' from gcompany where companyid=3)
```

Note that this query is incorrect unless `companyid` is `UNIQUE` or a `PRIMARY KEY`, since subqueries used in expressions must return at most one row.

If it's not unique or a primary key, you'll need to rephrase the query to use a join, or to use `LIKE ANY` using a subquery with `array_agg`.

Comment: i found the solution for it `select * from gtab47 where areaname ilike ''||(select place from gcompany where companyid=3)||'%'`

Comment: ` '(select place from gcompany where companyid=3)%' ` this wont return anything, need to append `'||` in both ends that is `''||(select place from gcompany where companyid=3)||'%'`  and it worked, anyways thanks for the comment

Comment: The only reason you'd need to concatenate to the empty string is if the data type of `place` is not text. Perhaps you want `place::text || '%'` ? (This is why you always show your error messages, and table definitions, in questions).